# Android String to Double Decimal Points

Tags: java, android, string, double, decimal

I am parsing A String value from the DB which has values like:

9.00, 9.44,
90.00, 90.44, 
180.00, 180.44

as Double and Storing it in a List Adapter and Inflate in a dialog box

This is the piece of code I am using for converting it to Double.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double tmp = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Double
                .parseDouble(string)));
```

But, when it converts into Double I can only get one Decimal Point. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
String string = "9.44";    
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

double tmp = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(Double
                .parseDouble(string)))
```

assings exactly the same value to tmp as shorter and simpler code

```
...    

double tmp = Double.parseDouble(string);
```

You should use BigDecimal instead of double if you need exact number of decimal points and the value has to be exact. If you store 1.00 as double you actually have 0.999...7 not 1.00

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
double tmp = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(string));
```

or

```
DecimalFormat("##.##")
```

Modify as per your requirement with #